# How can i calculate the sum of numbers written in a html table below specific headings - IONIC

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Explanation:** I have a html table with 2 columns namely `Debit` and `Credit`. Numers are written below them.

**Requirement:** I need to sum the number written below `Debit` and `Credit`

> Please open `about` page in the repo.........
>   Please find the **[stackblitz repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rvjjym)**

On the about page you will find 2 buttons , 1. `Total Debit`   2. `Total Credit`

I want to calculate the total amount under debit and credit once that specific button is clicked.

Adding image for your reference below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inVoiceItems` has each row in it. Create two methods, one for total debit and one for total credit.

```
public totalDebitValue = 0;
public totalCreditValue = 0;

totalDebit() {
    this.totalDebitValue = 0;
    this.inVoiceItems.forEach(e => {
        this.totalDebitValue += +e.prdDesc //+ is here to convert it to a number
    });
}

totalCredit() {
    this.totalCreditValue = 0;
    this.inVoiceItems.forEach(e => {
        this.totalCreditValue += +e.prdQty //+ is here to convert it to a number
    });
}
```

This will fail if the user inputs a value that cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: and how do i multiply, can you suggest here aswell - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349108/how-to-calculate-multiplication-of-numbers-in-a-html-table-below-specific-headin

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot [open it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSHDV.png)

**Declare Module**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute' ,
]);
```

**Create Filter**

create a filter to the addition of all value which is coming from an array.
it will add all value and it will return a total of value.

```
app.filter('totalAdditon', function() {
      return function(array_numbers) {
          var AmountTotal = 0;
          for (i=0; i<array_numbers.length; i++) {
              AmountTotal = AmountTotal + array_numbers[i];  
                          };
          return AmountTotal;
      };

  });
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $filter) {
      $scope.array_numbers = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8];   //values in array           
      $scope.CreditTotal = function() {
      var AmountTotal = $filter('totalAdditon')($scope.array_numbers);
      $scope.CreditTotal = AmountTotal; //bind the total value to HTML
    };
 });
```

**HTML**

Everytime you click on Total Credit Button, It will call a function Creditotal() to get the total value.

```
<div lan="eng" ng-app="myApp"> 
<table ng-controller="myController">
<tr ng-repeat="group in array_numbers">                                       
<td>{{group}}</td>  
 </tr>
 <tr class="total-rows" ><td>{{CreditTotal}} </td></tr>
 <tr><td><button ng-click="CreditTotal()">Total Credit</button><td></tr>
 </table>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Vendor: Angular, followed by our custom Javascripts -->
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/simplePagination.js"></script>   
 </div>
```

This is the process of addition of Credit value from table you can do the same to get a total of Debit.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: This is for Angular2+, not AngularJS

Comment: How do you say it's angular 2+?.

Comment: Because if you look at the question and the code from the question it's for Angular2+? It's also tagged with Angular and not AngularJS?

Comment: i'll share your question with someone who can answer this.