# How to calculate multiplication of numbers in a html table below specific headings - IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Explanation:** I have a html table with 3 columns namely `Price` , `Quantity` and `Total`. Numers are written below them.

**Requirement:** I need to multiply `price` with `Quantity` and bring that value in `Total`. I want to do this while leaving the quantity field or on a key press [as i am typing].

> **Image and code of my form are shared below**

Image:
[image]

code of `invoice.html`

```
<div style="margin-top:15px">
    <table>
       <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Total</th>

         <th></th>
       </tr>
       <tr *ngFor="let items of inVoiceItems2;let i=index;">
         <td>{{i+1}}</td> 
         <td style="width:198px"><input type="text" name="price" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems2[i].price" style="width:198px;border:0px"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems2[i].quantity" style="width:198px;border:0px"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="total" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems2[i].total" style="width:198px;border:0px"/></td>
       </tr>
   </table>  

   <br>
   <input type="button" value="Add New Row" (click)="addRow2()" style="margin-top:5px"/>
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="Calculate Bill" (click)="calculate_bill()" style="margin-top:5px"/>

 </div>
```

code of `invoice.ts`

```
  addRow2(){
    this.inVoiceItems2.push({'debit':'','credit':''});
  }

  calculate_bill(){

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the calculation when typing in the quantity field, you will need to use the `blur` event.

```
<td><input type="text" name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems2[i].quantity" style="width:198px;border:0px" (blur)="calculateRowTotal(i)"/></td>
```

the function would be something like this:

```
calculateRowTotal(i: number) {
    this.inVoiceItems2[i].total = +this.inVoiceItems2[i].price* +this.inVoiceItems2[i].quantity
}
```

NOTE: this will fail if the value being inserted cannot be converted to a `number`

Comment: [ts] Cannot find name 'i'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.i'?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic way, starting from your current setup.

Change the template for the `total` input to:

```
<input type="text" name="total" [ngModel]="getRowSum(inVoiceItems2[i].quantity, inVoiceItems2[i].price)" style="width:198px;border:0px"/>
```

Create the `getRowSum` method in `invoice.ts`:

```
getRowSum(qty, price) {
    const sum = qty * price;
    return isNaN(sum) ? '' : sum;
}
```